# Viewport change not working on some devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1400, initial-scale=1');
```

to change my viewport upon a button click. However, this is not working. The width of the device is not increasing at all. Is there something wrong with the code above?

Edit1:

When I test the script on Google's developer's console using the select devices options the code works fine. I tested it with iphone and other google devices. However when I test it in an actual phone it does not work.

Comment: why are you trying to change your viewport tag?

Comment: I am using html2pdf library to convert html to PDF in the client side. This library takes screen shoot of the screen and converts it to PDF. For this reason I need to covert mobile view to desktop view for a few seconds so that the library can take a screenshot. If the library takes screenshot of mobile view the PDF comes out really wacky